# Drag selected text inside textfield

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, drag

Someone faced the task, so that in a textfield the selected text could be moved inside the same textfield? Maybe there is some package for this? Or does anyone know how to write their own textfield?

So far I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I want to insert selected text to another position in textfield by drag-n-drop